# Is there any computational limitation (CPU usage) for Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running a heavy program on Bash in Windows, However, the task manager shows the CPU usage is only 14% (Intel i7-7700).

Is Windows Subsystem for Linux allowed to use the full potential of CPU?

Comment: If your program multithreaded?

Comment: I am not sure if the program is running in a single thread or not. If it does run only in a single thread, I guess 14% of CPU usage is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your process was single threaded 14% CPU usage on a quad core CPU seems reasonable.

It would be using about 55% of the single core. If you wanted to test, whether there are limitations to the linux subsystem, you could write a process, that *should* uses 100% (or at least very close) - execute it and watch your CPU usage. If the CPU usage isn't around 20-25% it would seem, that the subsystem is limited in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 14 % CPU usage on an i7-7700 for a single threaded program is expected.

You have 4 physical cores and 8 logical cores. Using a single logical core without boosting would put you at 100 % / 8 = 12 % usage. An [i7-7700](https://ark.intel.com/products/97128/Intel-Core-i7-7700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) can boost from 3.6 GHz to 4.2 GHz. That gives a theoretical max limit of (4.2 / 3.6) * (100 % / 8) = 14.0 %. Congratulations, your CPU is running at the maximum of 4.2 GHz! If you want better performance, you need to thread your application.

Your actual turbo boost speedup will depend on your CPU. I'm on a mobile i7-6820HQ. On CPU intensive tasks, I'm seeing about 16 % utilization, which is consistent with my speedup from turbo boost ( (3.6 GHz / 2.7 GHz) * (100 % / 8) = 16.0 ).